# why static_cast<int> fails to convert variable to an int

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++17, static-cast

I have the following code where I am trying to convert a variable to an integer, but as seen from the second last print, the type is still considered "d" - would anyone know how to get it to change to i, and thus have it behave as if it was initially initialised as `auto a = 2`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto a = 2.3;
    cout << typeid(a).name() << endl;
    a = static_cast<int>(a);
    cout << typeid(a).name() << endl;
    cout << a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

C++ is a statically typed language. The type of a variable doesn't change at runtime. If the type of variable is `double`, then it will never become anything else.

You can for example use another variable:

```
int b = a;
```

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate a bit on the other answers here, `static_cast<int>(a)` does indeed convert the value stored in `a` to an `int`.  However, when the result is assigned back to `a`, it is *implicitly converted* back to a `double` because the type of the variable `a` was deduced to be `double`.

These two lines of code are effectively equivalent:

```
a = static_cast<double>(static_cast<int>(a));

// There is the same conversion to double here, but it's implicit:
a = static_cast<int>(a);
```

Note that the special `auto` "type" does not declare a variable to be of *any* type; rather it instructs the compiler to figure out what the type should be based on the value being assigned to the variable.  Since `2.3` is a literal of type `double`, the compiler deduces the type of `a` to be `double`.

You cannot change the type of a variable after declaration. You either need a new variable, or you can use a type capable of holding differently-typed values, such as [`std::variant<double, int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Answer (score -2):

Unlike function, where you can perform overloading, variables in c++ are statically invariant and remain as of the same type as these are declared. In your code you are statically type casting like
`static_cast<int>(a)` Now, the value in a is a double literal and is type-casted to an integer literal, but **a** will remain to the same type in which it is declared.
Therefore, you will get your right hand side be evaluated as value **2**.

Comment: I think you have the right idea, but it's a very hard answer to read.